# The proof of comparing the fractions.

Tags: proof-writing, fractions

Hi I came up with this method but couldn't find any proof can you provide one thanks

To compare $\frac{a}{b}$ with $\frac{c}{d}$ , compare the cross products as follows:

If ad > bc, then:
$\frac{a}{b}$>$\frac{c}{d}$

If ad < bc, then:
$\frac{a}{b}$>$\frac{c}{d}$

If ad = bc, then:
$\frac{a}{b}$ = $\frac{c}{d}$

I mean how can we conclude the bigger or smaller ones.

Comment: If $a=2,c=1,b=d=-1$?

Comment: You haven't reversed the inequality for the second condition...

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! After correction, this is valid only if the product of the denominators is positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy applying the basic rule  for use of inequalities:

> You can multiply an inequality by any number $C$ without reversing the inequality if $C>0$, reversing it if $C<0$.

So here, starting from $\frac ab<\frac cd$, if you multiply by $bd$,

- If $b,d$ have the same sign, $bd>0$ and therefore
  $$\frac a{\not b} \cdot \not bd <\frac c{\not d}d\cdot b\not d\iff ad<bc.$$
- If $b,d$ have different signs, $bd<$ so
  $$\frac a{\not b} \cdot \not bd >\frac c{\not d}d\cdot b\not d\iff ad>bc.$$

Answer (score 0):

Simply note that $\dfrac ab$ is greater than $\dfrac cd$ if $$\dfrac ab -\dfrac cd >0 \implies \dfrac{ad-bc}{bd} >0$$

Now, your method only works if $bd>0$. Similarly reverse the inequality for the other case.

Comment: I think I should let the math go :)